# Facebook LIKE fires error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating application on localhost (XAMPP). When I try to test LIKE button this error pop ups:

```
**Message Failed: This message contains content that has been blocked by our security systems.**
```

Comment: I think the URL you're using may be blocked by Facebook - you should use one which isn't blocked

Answer (score 0):

Either the URL you wanted to like is blocked by Facebook or you are trying to like a Link on localhost - which is not possible, of course. You can only like public URLs.

Put the URL in the Facebook Debugger to check if it´s available: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

You can also just try to post it on your own Facebook Wall to test if it is blocked.

Comment: I am trying to create facebook app on localhost (for my school project). I ll try to find some free webhosting with SSL. Thank you for your answer. I guess problem is that I am hosting on localhost...

Comment: why would you need SSL? you only need SSL for page/tab apps and canvas apps, but not if you want to implement a facebook app on an external website.

Answer (score 0):

go to the link given below: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

1. Type your link in URL to Like. for example: https://www.facebook.com/games/rajvirbalapp/
2. Type width in next input box.
3. Select your Like button Layout from drop down. For Example: box_count.
4. Select Action Type from Drop down. For example: Like.
5. Tick Show Friends' Faces or Include Share Button if you want to show share button.
6. Click Get Code button and copy the script and paste where you want to show the like button in your website.

If you use localhost then it will display error message other wise it work's.

Best of luck.